# function template specialization generating link error

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, linker-errors, template-specialization

I had previously asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56696510/1757805) question that involved using auto with variadic templates that generates a tuple and the proper way to iterate over them. User [metalfox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6350078/metalfox) had provided me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56699248/1757805) solution.

I tried their solution and this is what my full code looks like including my namespace that I had omitted in the original.

**calc.h**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

namespace math {

    template<class... T>
    class expression_t {
    public:
        std::tuple<T...> rhs;
        std::size_t size = sizeof...(T);

        //expression_t(const T&... args) : rhs{ args... } {}

        template <class... Args>
        expression_t(Args&& ...args) : rhs(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

        std::tuple<T...> operator()() const {
            return rhs;
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    void Print(std::ostream& os, T x) {
        os << x;
    }

    template<>
    void Print<char>(std::ostream& os, char x) {
        if (x == '+' || x == '-' || x == '*' || x == '/' || x == '%')
            os << ' ' << x << ' ';
    }

    template<class... Args>
    expression_t<Args...> expression(Args... args) {
        expression_t<Args...> expr(args...);
        return expr;
    }

    template<class... Args>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const expression_t<Args...>& expr) {
        auto Fn = [&os](auto... x) {
            (Print(os, x), ...);
        };

        std::apply(Fn, expr.rhs);

        os << '\n';
        return os;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "calc.h"

using namespace math;

int main() {
    double x = 0;    
    auto expr = expression(4, x, '^', 2, '+', 2, x);
    auto t = expr();
    std::cout << std::get<2>(t);
    std::cout << expr;
    return 0;
}
```

It is generating this linker error during the build process:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ChemLab, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl math::Print<char>(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,char)" (??$Print@D@math@@YAXAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@D@Z) already defined in calc.obj
1>C:\***\test.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Done building project "ChemLab.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What is the proper way to declare-define these print functions to prevent them from being defined multiple times in a single translation unit?

Comment: Do you have other files that include `calc.h` in them in this project?

Comment: The error message suggests that `calc.cpp` also includes `calc.h`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik your are correct I do have calc.cpp because I have other functions defined there that are inside of another nested namespace not shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function template specialization - like `Print<char>` in your example - is a regular function, not a template. It must be defined exactly once, or else defined with `inline` keyword.

Comment: Okay so I need the inline keyword.

Comment: Either that, or declare the function in the header and define in a source file, just like you would a non-template function.

Comment: I tried defining it in calc.cpp but still generates the link error.

Comment: You did something wrong, then.

Comment: @FrancisCugler When you defined it in the cpp fie, did you still have the declaration for the specialization in the header file?

Comment: Adding the `inline` keyword to the explicit `print<char>` function did the trick! It is now building and displaying output, now it's a matter of checking my output and making sure it is behaving as expected.